# NSMutableArray (1 dim) from NSArray (2dim)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to make 1 array that will hold all of the other arrays objects and will look like this

```
 ("052-6224754","03-6475075","02-6753231")
```

my code is:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) getRecepientsPhones
{
NSMutableArray* phones = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//scroll all choosed contacts and retrieve phones to nsstring
if([recepientsFromContacts count]>0)
    for (int i=0; i<[recepientsFromContacts count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableArray* tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        if(![[[recepientsFromContacts objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"CPhones"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        {
            [tempArray addObject:[[recepientsFromContacts objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"CPhones"]];
            for(int j = 0; j<[tempArray count];j++)
            {
                [phones addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:j]];
            }
        }
    }
//lets fetch from that contact
if([personRecepient count]>0)
{
    if(![[personRecepient objectForKey:@"CellPhone"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        [phones addObject:[personRecepient objectForKey:@"CellPhone"]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",phones);
return phones;
```

}

```
[[recepientsFromContacts objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"CPhones"]
```

is 1 or more dimension array (it is array of phone numbers per person , person can have more than 1 number)
example: ("052-6224754","03-6475075")

but my function returns

("052-6224754","03-6475075"),("02-6753231")

which is not good , what should I do to make it 1 array 
        ("052-6224754","03-6475075","02-6753231")

Comment: It takes mor effort than nessesary to understand your question. Could you enhance the readability by using proper example data and indent the code correctly?

Comment: Sure I will update :)

Comment: Just don't call this numbers :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the line

```
[phones addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:j]];
```

to

```
[phones addObjectsFromArray:[tempArray objectAtIndex:j]];
```

This should result in a flattened array of phone numbers.

Then you should head over to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) because there are several issues with your code fragment.

**Edit:** Here's a cleaned up version of the method:

```
- (NSArray *)recepientsPhoneNumbers
{
    NSMutableArray* phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in _recepientsFromContacts)
    {
        id recipientPhoneNumbers = dict[@"CPhones"];
        if (recipientPhoneNumbers != [NSNull null])
            [phoneNumbers addObjectsFromArray:recipientPhoneNumbers];
    }

    id recipientPhoneNumbers = _personRecepient[@"CellPhone"];
    if (recipientPhoneNumbers != [NSNull null])
        [phoneNumbers addObjectsFromArray:recipientPhoneNumbers];

    NSLog(@"%@", phoneNumbers);

    return phoneNumbers;
}
```

I applied Cocoa coding conventions, so ivars are now prefixed with underscores.

Comment: If "working" is good for you, fine. Code quality is a major concern in most projects I'm on, and "working" is a very low rating for a piece of code. I'd suggest you take the time to post your code on codereview. You'll learn a lot about Cocoa conventions, style, readability and redundant pieces in your code.

Comment: Oh I see , thanks :)
well it is my first , and I suppose last xCode project , so i will thionk about

Comment: @user2957713: Xcode (not xCode) is an IDE, you can write Objective-C with any editor. You should have high standard expectation for any software project.

Comment: Educative Edit :) 
About conventions: should I follow them ? it will take like 3 days to search and replace all of my ivars with underscopes :(